# Как в django использовать две модели в одном шаблоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Вопрос, имеется две модели, не связанные между собой.
Вот две модели из models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="", verbose_name=_("Название работы"))
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, default="", verbose_name=_("URL"))
    in_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default="", verbose_name=_("Категория"))
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType, verbose_name=_("Тип Элемента"))
    description = models.TextField(_('Описание'), null=True, blank=True)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Images, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Изображения"))
    sort = models.IntegerField(default="0", verbose_name=_("Сортировка"))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default="True", verbose_name=_("Активно?"))
    date_pub = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Дата добавления"))
    date_upd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, verbose_name=_("Дата редактирования"))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/portfolio/items/%s/" % self.slug

    def get_category_url(self):
        return "/portfolio/category/%s/" % self.in_category.slug

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Элемент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Элементы'

class Settings(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="", verbose_name=_("Наименование"))
    category_type = models.ForeignKey(CategoryType, verbose_name=_("Тип категория"))
    sort = models.IntegerField(default="0", verbose_name=_("Сортировка"))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default="True", verbose_name=_("Активно?"))
    date_pub = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Дата добавления"))
    date_upd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, verbose_name=_("Дата редактирования"))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Настройка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Настройки'
```

Вот класс из views.py

```
class ItemList(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'itm_portfolio/main.html'
```

Во общем собственно вопрос, как можно вывести в шаблон main.html данные из модели Settings, помимо данных из модели Item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение оказалось довольно простым:
views.py

```
class ItemList(ListView):
model = Item
template_name = 'itm_portfolio/main.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ItemList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['settings'] = Settings.objects.all()
    return context
```

Далее в main.html выводим данные из модели Settings:

```
    {% for item in settings %}
        {{ item.category_type }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись без `get_context_data`.

```
class ItemList(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'itm_portfolio/main.html'

    @staticmethod
    def all_settings():
        return Settings.objects.all()
```

В шаблоне вызывать так:

```
{{ view.all_settings }}
```